# request content type and emty request body

Tags: json, express

Good morning ,this is my server'config :

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //true

// override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in req
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
```

when the API is used in the browser the request content type is set to *text/plain* and it returns 500 Internal Server Error. When I do a

```
console.log(req.body)
```

it is empty and when I test it with HTTP requester and set the content type to "application/json" it works normally.
I am confused and hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you only have configue body-parser to parse JSON and URL-encoded data... if you want to read text/plain you have to add `app.use(bodyParser.text());` as it is said here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparsertextoptions

Comment: thanks for your quick answer , i added it but still get the error

Comment: can you edit your question to display the whole script then please (don't hesitate to use triple `  to write code blocks )

Comment: the console.log parses the request body now it returns it but then it shows this error  Cannot read property 'UDID' of undefined which is in the req.body (i don't get it , i mean it reads the req .body it is not emty why it is undefined)

Comment: either your udid property in your request is not set or you may use it in your script without it has been set .

Comment: when i restarted the sever it accually show the same mistake again this is the request body :{"initObj":{"UDID":"1256"}} and it shows the same in the console.log(req.body) but then i did a console.log(req.body.initObj) it returns undefined sorry but i really can't figure out what is the problem

Comment: usually if you have an "undefined" it's because your variable or the one you try to access is not set, i assume your request is text/plain so you probably need to parse it with JSON.parse(req.body) as it's considered as a string.

Comment: i wad just doing that i just added                           JSON.stringify(req.body);
console.log(req.body.initObj); but returns undefined the problem when i test whith http requester and put the content type application/json it returns the result correctly

Comment: then why don't you use application/json ? (try to find the type of req.body using `typeof()`

Comment: well i have some restraints but i will change it i think thank you very much  :)